# What is DatagramPacket offset in java and how it is used?

Tags: java, networking, offset, datagram

I find it hard to find a comprehensible, simple information/explanation for the next question:

*What is the DatagramPacket offset?* it is being mentioned a lot of times in the doc.oracle:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html#DatagramPacket(byte[],%20int)

but I can't find a clear explanation of *what it is and how is it used*.

Would very much appreciate a simple explanation from one (or more!) of you experts, and if it is possible and you find it relevant, maybe also few words on DatagramPocket itself.

Thank you.

Comment: many the methods in the Java SDK will allow you to specify data within a byte array, at an offset and a given length, if for whatever reason, that's where you need to source your data from.  but most of the time, you simply want to read or write data into the start of the byte array, at offset zero.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @slipperyseal. It makes it clearer